# Oracle 10g ODBC Connection fails in MS Access 2010, but works in ODBC Control Panel

Tags: oracle, ms-access, odbc

I set up a DSN for an Oracle 10g database (old, I know) on 64 bit Windows 7 with the 32 bit ODBC control panel.  That connection tests successfully.

When I try to connect to the same DSN from inside of Access 2010, I get the following error:

> ODBC--call failed.
>
> [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specificed
>
> (#12154)[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Driver's SQLSetConnectAttr failed IM006 0 [Microsoft]ODBC Driver Manager] Driver's SQLSetConnectAttr failed (#0)

TNS ping finds my TNS name just fine.  The 'Test Connection' button from inside of the ODBC control panel screen works just fine.  The same screen invoked from within MS Access shows that error above.  It looks like Access invokes some shared library in Office 2010 to make the connection that wraps the libraries used by the ODBC control panel and drivers.  I get the same error if I try to make the connection using MS Query 3.0.

Googling around didn't find much, because TNS issues are so common.  I'm 99% sure this is a problem in how Office libraries wrap the ODBC libraries.  The closest thing I saw in my search was a question here on SO where the asker discovered that Access was finding a different sqlnet.ora file than he intended it to use.  Once he renamed that extra sqlnet file, it worked fine.  I've renamed every one on my disk except for the one in my admin/network folder, and still can't make the connection.

I'm really at a loss here, folks.  Any idea one what I could try?  In the mean time, I'm going to try to write a quick VBA script that will try to manually make the connection.

Comment: Are you sure you open the 32 bit ODBC panel? When you just enter `odbcad32.exe` it opens the 64 bit version! You must run `c:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe` for 32 bit.

Comment: Yep; I used that path to load it directly.  I did not launch it from the control panel.  Thanks.

Comment: Update: I tried using Excel to open the same connection.  I get the same error if I try to use a DSN again (expected), but then I tried to create the connection with OLE DB.  Doing that, I get

> ORA-06413: Connection not open.

This would seem to point to another issue with the path to the settings used by driver: https://community.oracle.com/message/11103466

Comment: Update: Using MS Access 2016 to connect to the same DSN results in the same error.

Comment: If I try to create a new DSN from within the Access 2016 window, I get a similar error.  It looks like something about how both Access versions run is throwing off the file path used to load the driver.  Let me check the ORACLE_HOME sys variable.

Comment: I think I found the issue.  There's a sqlnet.log file in my "my documents" folder that is full of errors like this: 

"Fatal NI connect error 6413, connecting to:" [the oracle connection string]

The problem is that the path to the access EXE has been appended to that connection string, and it includes "Program Files (x86)" as part of it.  That error code says it's a failure parsing the connection string because of the extra ().  I'm going to confirm this by installing 64 bit office 2010, and if it works will reply as an answer.